# Create a new NSExpression

Tags: xamarin, monomac, nsexpression, nspredicateeditor

How can i create a `NSExpression` with a constant value for using with the `PredicateEditor`.

for Example:

the leftExpression should be a string "state", the rightExpression should be as string "Germany"

i've tried:

```
NSExpression left = new NSExpression(NSExpressionType.ConstantValue);
left.SetValueForKey(new NSString("state"), new NSString("Germany"));
```

but this does not work. The Programm stops without error!

Answer (score 1):

Use the static method `NSExpression NSExpression.FromConstant(NSObject)`:

```
var left = NSExpression.FromConstant((NSString)"Germany");
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss to throw the generated Exception with:

```
throw left;
```

Comment: the programm stop while left.SetValueForKey. So i can not do throw left;

Comment: OK, i don't want to throw left, i would like to create an NSExpression for the leftExpression of a NSPredicate.Subpredicates[].LeftExpression. I was looking for several hours but i did not find the right way.